# How to solve $x^3 + 2y^3 + 3z^3 = 4xyz$ for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory

solve $x^3 + 2y^3 + 3z^3 = 4xyz$ for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}$

My main question is how to solve this in $\mathbb{Q}$, i know how to solve these kind of problems in $\mathbb{Z}$, where i usually look at modulo small primes, such as 3,5. But with $\mathbb{Q}$ i get totally confused, any smart methods i can use solving this?

Kees

Comment: The equations in the title and in the question body do not agree.

Comment: sharp thank you, i will edit it right away

Comment: Looking modulo small primes only generally helps you show that you can't find a solution..

Comment: true that, but if you can prove this equation has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$, you can conclude it has no solutions in $\mathbb{Q}$, unless we have (0,0,0) of course...?

Comment: so that's the reason i always try that actually, if there is another method that can be used i would be much obliged to hear it :)

Comment: Right, no non-zero solutions.

Comment: Please don't add a post-script that changes the question dramatically - just edit the question to reflect your new question. Consider a reader who is reading the question for the first time, not somebody re-reading the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If integer $X,Y,Z$ are solutions of $$X^3+2Y^3+3Z^3=4XYZ,\tag{1}$$

then for any integer $D\ne 0$ one will have

$$
\left(\frac{X}{D}\right)^3 +
2\left(\frac{Y}{D}\right)^3 +
3\left(\frac{Z}{D}\right)^3 =
4\frac{X}{D}\frac{Y}{D}\frac{Z}{D}.
$$

So, one will have rational solution $(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{X}{D},\frac{Y}{D},\frac{Z}{D}\right)$.

But equation $(1)$ has no nontrivial solutions.
If it will have nontrivial solution $(X,Y,Z)$, then denote $G = GCD(X,Y,Z)$.
Then denote $X_0=X/G$, $Y_0=Y/G$, $Z_0=Z/G$, and $(X_0,Y_0,Z_0)$ will be solution of $(1)$ too.

Now, consider all by modulo 7.
Since $GCD(X_0,Y_0,Z_0)=1$, then they all cannot be divisible by $7$.

$0^3\equiv 0 (\bmod 7)$,

$1^3\equiv 1 (\bmod 7)$,

$2^3\equiv 1 (\bmod 7)$,

$3^3\equiv -1 (\bmod 7)$,

$4^3\equiv 1 (\bmod 7)$,

$5^3\equiv -1 (\bmod 7)$,

$6^3\equiv -1 (\bmod 7)$.

Considering all possible values of  $X_0,Y_0,Z_0 (\bmod 7)$ in the $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}^3$, one will get only solution $(0,0,0)$, which mean that $X_0,Y_0,Z_0$ all are divisible by $7$. So, only one integer solution exists: $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: hmmmm, isn't gcd(x,y,z) not supposed to be 1 as well then?

Comment: If you just want to find *a* rational solution, you might as well just pick $X,Y,Z$. The key is that *any* rational solution is of this form.

Comment: @Kees, I don't get clearly... The equation is homogeneous, so if it has nontrivial solution, then this solution can be scaled by any factor (let it be $1/D$). Is gcd(x,y,z) important?

Comment: o no never mind, i am looking at integer solutions again :(

Comment: @Kees, consider modulo $7$. I'll explain now in the answer abowe...